# Why didn't my buy limit order become the highest bid?

Tags: united-states, stocks, limit-order, bid-ask

I am trying to buy a stock that is $307 bid and $312 offered. I placed a buy limit order for 1 share at $307.10. However, the best bid remained at $307.00. After an hour, the best bid is still $307.00. Why didn't my limit order become the highest bid?

[image: Screenshot of thinkorswim web]

Comment: Somewhat related: [Limit order not executed despite price going below my limit](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/124914)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Odd lots (less than 100 shares) are not covered by NBBO regulations and they do not update the quote.  [Read this](https://www.investopedia.com/odd-lot-trading-on-the-rise-4774753).